# Efficient neighbourhood search in numpy ndarray instead of nested conditional for loops

Tags: python, performance, numpy, nested-loops, neighbours

Although there are many instances of the question: "What is the numpy alternative to nested for loops", I was unable to find a suitable answer for my case. Here it goes:

I have a 3D numpy array with "0" background and other integers as foreground. I would like to find and store the foreground voxels which fall within a predefined mask (a sphere defining a given distance from a reference node). I have successfully done the task using nested 'for' loops and a chain of 'if' conditions as shown below. I am looking for a more efficient and compact alternative to avoid the loops and long conditions for this neighborhood search algorithm.

sample input data:

```
import numpy as np

im = np.array([[[ 60, 54, 47, 52, 57, 53, 46, 48]
, [ 60, 57, 53, 53, 54, 53, 50, 55]
, [ 60, 63, 56, 58, 59, 57, 50, 50]
, [ 70, 70, 64, 69, 74, 72, 64, 47]
, [ 73, 76, 77, 80, 82, 76, 58, 37]
, [ 85, 85, 86, 86, 78, 62, 38, 20]
, [ 94, 94, 92, 78, 54, 33, 16, 255]
, [ 94, 90, 72, 51, 32, 19, 255, 255]
, [ 65, 53, 29, 18, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 29, 22, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]]

, [[ 66, 67, 70, 69, 75, 73, 72, 63]
, [ 68, 70, 73, 74, 78, 80, 74, 53]
, [ 75, 87, 87, 83, 89, 86, 61, 33]
, [ 81, 89, 88, 98, 99, 77, 41, 18]
, [ 84, 94, 100, 100, 82, 49, 21, 255]
, [ 99, 101, 92, 75, 48, 25, 255, 255]
, [ 93, 77, 52, 32, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 52, 40, 25, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 23, 16, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]]

, [[ 81, 83, 92, 101, 101, 83, 49, 19]
, [ 86, 96, 103, 103, 95, 64, 28, 255]
, [ 94, 103, 107, 98, 79, 41, 255, 255]
, [101, 103, 98, 79, 51, 28, 255, 255]
, [102, 97, 76, 49, 27, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 79, 62, 35, 21, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 33, 23, 15, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 16, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]]

, [[106, 107, 109, 94, 58, 26, 15, 255]
, [110, 104, 90, 66, 37, 19, 255, 255]
, [106, 89, 61, 35, 22, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 76, 56, 34, 19, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 40, 27, 18, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 17, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]

, [[ 68, 51, 33, 19, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 45, 34, 20, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 28, 18, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [ 17, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]

, [[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]

, [[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]

, [[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255, 255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [255,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
, [  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

The implemented method:

```
[Z,Y,X]=im.shape
RN = np.array([3,4,4])     
################Loading Area search
rad = 3
a,b,c = RN
x,y,z = np.ogrid[-c:Z-c,-b:Y-b,-a:X-a]
neighborMask = x*x + y*y + z*z<= rad*rad
noNodeMask = im > 0
mask = np.logical_and(neighborMask, noNodeMask)

imtemp = im.copy()
imtemp[mask] = -1

for i in range (X):
    for j in range (Y):
        for k in range (Z):
            if imtemp[i,j,k]==-1:
                if i in (0, X-1) or j in (0, Y-1) or k in (0, Z-1): 
                    imtemp[i,j,k]=-2
                elif imtemp[i+1,j,k] == 0 or imtemp[i-1,j,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j+1,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j-1,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j,k+1] == 0 or imtemp[i,j,k-1] == 0:
                    imtemp[i,j,k]=-2
                    
LA = np.argwhere(imtemp==-2)
```

The resulting LA from the above sample code is:

```
In [90]:LA
Out[90]: 
array([[4, 4, 0],
       [4, 4, 6],
       [4, 5, 5],
       [4, 6, 4],
       [4, 6, 5],
       [4, 7, 3],
       [5, 3, 5],
       [5, 4, 4],
       [5, 4, 5],
       [5, 5, 3],
       [5, 5, 4],
       [5, 6, 2],
       [5, 6, 3],
       [6, 2, 4],
       [6, 3, 3],
       [6, 3, 4],
       [6, 4, 2],
       [6, 4, 3],
       [6, 5, 1],
       [6, 5, 2]])
```

And a slice in Z direction (an XY plane instance) which shows different untouched, masked (-1), and target (-2) nodes:
[image: a sample slice of the original and masked matrices]

Comment: Did you mean to make the inner ranges from 1 to X/Y - 1? In the first iteration (`i=0`) `imtemp[i-1, j, k]` doesn't fail, but it's the last element in the first axis...

Comment: I had to reverse the orders due to the "im" array being read from an MHD image. But the ranges are OK in the given example. I am not quite sure what you mean by "1 to X/Y".

Comment: This loop looks wrong: `for j in range (Y-1):`. So does the one inside it

Comment: Also, `if i==(Z-1):` makes a big flat map of -2 at the bottom of the image, outside the sphere

Comment: Can you conceptually explain how you want the shell to be made?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the help offer below. So I compiled the code with the sample data for im on my system and it seems to me to work properly. However, since the X and Z dimensions here are actually equal, to avoid confusion (the inverse corrds are due to MHD reader and I have dealt with it), I edited the loop indices. I have also included the LA result and a snapshot of a slice showing the correct shell nodes. for the conceptual explanation read next comment:

Comment: Imagine a ball inside a cube. the ball nodes have >0 values where the rest of the cube is 0. I would like to find the location of nodes on the surface of the ball which fall within a smaller sphere which intersects with the ball.

Comment: So if the cube intersects the ball, you don't want the sides of the cube to be part of the ball? Because some sides currently are in your loop, and others wrap around unintentionally.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I do want to include the sides which intersect with the ball AND are within the mask. In the current code, I have included that condition only for the "top" side of the cube before going into the neighbourhood search. I should correct it to include all sides though.

Comment: Could you do that? I want to replicate the exact result you get, and I'm pretty sure that what you have now is inconsistent/incorrect

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done!

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I noticed that you have one more mistake caused by the fact that sometimes you index dimensions forwards, sometimes backwards. The limits of your loops are backwards. It should either be `for i in range(Z)`, or `X, Y, Z = im.shape`. The only reason this is not crashing is because `X==Z` by coincidence.

Comment: That being said, I reproduce your results exactly. Took me a while to realize you were doing `... <= rad*rad`, while I was using `<` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Statement**

You have a "solid" shape in a large array. You carve out a ball from that. Your goal is to find the indices of the surface of the solid within the ball. Surfaces are defined as any point neighboring the outside of the solid with 6-point connectivity. Edges of the array are considered to be surfaces too.

**Faster Loop Solution**

You already computed the mask that represents the intersection of the solid and the ball. You can compute the mask a little more elegantly and convert it to indices instead. I suggest keeping the order of your dimensions constant, instead of switching between different notations. The order of `RN` is affected, for example, and you run the risk of mismatching your axis limits.

```
RN = np.array([4, 4, 3])
rad = 3

im = ...

cutout = ((np.indices(im.shape) - RN.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1))**2).sum(axis=0) <= rad**2
solid = im > 0
mask = solid & cutout
indices = np.argwhere(mask)
```

You can also get the cutout without reshaping `RN` by doing

```
cutout = ((np.rollaxis(np.indices(im.shape, sparse=False), 0, 4) - RN)**2).sum(axis=-1) <= rad**2
```

The nice thing about computing indices is that your loops don't need to be huge any more. By using `argwhere`, you basically strip off the outer three loops, leaving only the `if` statement to loop over. You can also vectorize the connectivity check. This has the nice side effect that you can define arbitrary connectivity for each pixel.

```
limit = np.array(im.shape) - 1  # Edge of `im`
connectivity = np.array([[ 1,  0,  0],  # Add rows to determine connectivity
                         [-1,  0,  0],
                         [ 0,  1,  0],
                         [ 0, -1,  0],
                         [ 0,  0,  1],
                         [ 0,  0, -1]], dtype=indices.dtype)
index_mask = np.ones(len(indices), dtype=bool)

for n, ind in enumerate(indices):
    if ind.all() and (ind < limit).all() and im[tuple((ind + connectivity).T)].all():
        index_mask[n] = False

LA = indices[index_mask, :]
```

Notice that there is really no point to `imtemp` at all. Even in your original loop, you could just manipulate `mask` directly. Instead of setting elements to `-2` when they pass your criterion, you could set elements to `False` if they didn't.

I do something like that here. We check each of the indices that were actually selected, and determine if any of them are inside the solid. These indices are eliminated from the mask. The list of indices is then updated based on the mask.

The check `ind.all() and (ind < limit).all() and im[tuple((ind + connectivity).T)].all()` is a shortcut for what you were doing with the `or` conditions, but reversed (testing for non-surface rather than surface).

- `ind.all()` checks that none of the indices are zero: i.e., not on a top/front/left surface.
- `(ind < limit).all()` checks that none of the indices are equal to the corresponding image size minus one.
- `im[tuple((ind + connectivity).T)].all()` checks that none of the connected pixels are zero. `(ind + connectivity).T` is a `(3, 6)` array of the six points that we are connected to (currently defined as +/-1 in each axis by the `(6, 3)` `connectivity` array). When you turn it into a tuple, it just becomes a fancy index, as if you had done something like `im[x + connectivity[:, 0], y + connectivity[:, 1], z + connectivity[:, 2]]`. The commas in the index just make it into a tuple. They way I show is better suited for arbitrary numbers of dimensions.

Pixels that pass all three tests are inside the solid, and get removed. You can of course write the loop to check the other way, but then you would have to alter your mask:

```
index_mask = np.zeros(len(indices), dtype=bool)

for n, ind in enumerate(indices):
    if (ind == 0).any() or (ind == limit).any() or (im[tuple((ind + connectivity).T)] == 0).any():
        index_mask[n] = True

LA = indices[index_mask, :]
```

Looping manually is not ideal by any means. However, it shows you how to shorten the loop (probably by a couple of orders of magnitude), and how to define arbitrary connectivity using vectorization and broadcasting, without getting bogged down with hard-coding it.

**Fully Vectorized Solution**

The loops above can be fully vectorized using the magic of broadcasting. Instead of looping over each row in `indices`, we can add `connectivity` to it in bulk and filter the results in bulk. The trick is to add enough dimensions that you add all of `connectivity` to *each* element of `indices`.

You will still want to omit the pixels that are at the edges:

```
edges = (indices == 0).any(axis=-1) | (indices == limit).any(axis=-1)
conn_index = indices[~edges, None, :] + connectivity[None, ...]

index_mask = np.empty(len(indices), dtype=bool)
index_mask[edges] = True
index_mask[~edges] = (im[tuple(conn_index.T)] == 0).any(axis=0)

LA = indices[index_mask, :]
```

I expect that a properly written loop compiled with numba will be significantly faster than this solution, because it will avoid much of the overhead with pipelining the operations. It will not require large temporary buffers or special handling.

**TL;DR**

```
# Parameters
RN = np.array([4, 4, 3])
rad = 3

im = ...

# Find subset of interest
cutout = ((np.indices(im.shape) - RN.reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1))**2).sum(axis=0) <= rad**2
solid = im > 0

# Convert mask to indices
indices = np.argwhere(solid & cutout)

# Find image edges among indices
edges = (indices == 0).any(axis=-1) | (indices == limit).any(axis=-1)

# Connectivity elements for non-edge pixels
conn_index = indices[~edges, None, :] + connectivity[None, ...]

# Mask the valid surface pixels
index_mask = np.empty(len(indices), dtype=bool)
index_mask[edges] = True
index_mask[~edges] = (im[tuple(conn_index.T)] == 0).any(axis=0)

# Final result
LA = indices[index_mask, :]
```

Comment: WOW! This is a short course on the subject :) Thanks so much for taking the time and elaborating on every possible detail of your solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Since your loops are only using direct Numpy indexing, you can use the **Numba's `@njit`** to perform this in a *much more efficient* way.

```py
@njit
def compute_imtemp(imtemp, X, Y, Z):
    for i in range (Z):
        for j in range (Y-1):
            for k in range (X-1):
                if imtemp[i,j,k]==-1:
                    if i==(Z-1): 
                        imtemp[i,j,k]=-2
                    elif imtemp[i+1,j,k] == 0 or imtemp[i-1,j,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j+1,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j-1,k] == 0 or imtemp[i,j,k+1] == 0 or imtemp[i,j,k-1] == 0:
                        imtemp[i,j,k]=-2

[...]
imtemp = im.copy()
imtemp[mask] = -1
compute_imtemp(imtemp, X, Y, Z)
LA = np.argwhere(imtemp==-2)
```

Here are performance results on my machine:

```
281 µs ± 1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
776 ns ± 16.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The Numba implementation is *362 times faster*.

Note that the first call to `compute_imtemp` will be slow because of the compilation. One way to overcome this is to call `compute_imtemp` on an empty Numpy array. Another way is to manually compile the function using the Numba API and provide the types to Numba explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Jerome for this solution. I was not familiar with Numba. I implemented it successfully. I am still wondering if you think there is also a more "compact" way of writing these loops and conditions?

Comment: @Silent. I'd be happy to show you if you explain exactly what you want. No guarantee that a pure numpy solution will be faster though, since a compiled loop is actually more efficient in most cases.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the offer. I edited the question to reflect your concerns. I would be okay to learn any elegant way of doing this regardless of it being numpy, since at the end I can easily convert the results to numpy and move on.

Comment: Any chance I could ask you to benchmark my solution as well?